# Paging UIScrollView on custom UITableViewCell with Autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to use a horizontal-paging `UIScrollView` in my custom `UITableViewCell` using Autolayout. I've successfully added the `UIScrollView` to the cell with all the proper constraints.[image]

My problem arises when I try to load the `UIScrollView` with views. I'm overriding the custom cell's `layoutSubviews` method and loading the ScrollView's views there because it's the only method I could find where Autolayout's constraints had been loaded. Thus, giving me accurate references to the ScrollView's size.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    for(int i=0; i<self.scrollArray.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        CGFloat width = self.theScrollView.frame.size.width;
        frame.origin.x = width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.theScrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [subview addSubview:[self.scrollArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.theScrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.theScrollView.frame.size.width * self.scrollArray.count, self.theScrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.theScrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
    self.theScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}
```

However, `layoutSubviews` is called multiple times on my cell and thus adding more subviews than necessary to my `UIScrollView`. Is there a better method to load my subviews in that I'm not aware of? Or is there a way to use `layoutSubviews` but make sure my subviews are only loaded once into the `UIScrollView`?

Comment: One simple solution is store a boolean property that you set when you first add the subviews.  If this property is YES on subsequent calls to layout subviews then don't add them again.  Alternatively add the scrollview to the cell and expose it via a property, then add the subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thanks for your response. From what I've noticed, the constraints are set only on the final call to `layoutSubviews`, meaning I'd need some way to detect the final call, or if the constraints are set. Also, I tried adding the subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and the constraints aren't set yet there either.

Comment: If the subviews are already there then you can still call `layoutIfNeeded` and/or resize the subviews, you just need to make sure you only add them once

Comment: Separate the logics of adding subviews to the scrollview and setting frames of them. In layoutsubviews, it's better to have setting frames logic only.

Answer (score 1):

Move the part where you add the subviews to the scrollview to where you set the scrollArray and added the subviews to subview array property. In layoutsubviews, you should deal with setting frame only.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //    self.theScrollView.frame = Make sure you set the scroll view frame;
    for(int i=0; i<self.scrollArray.count; i++) 
    {
        UIView *aView = [self.scrollArray objectAtIndex:i];
        aView.frame = CGRectMake(self.theScrollView.frame.size.width * i, 0, self.theScrollView.frame.size.width, self.theScrollView.frame.size.height);
    }

    self.theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.theScrollView.frame.size.width * self.scrollArray.count, self.theScrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.theScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

}

- (void)partWhereYouSetScrollArray
{
    for(int i=0; i<self.scrollArray.count; i++)
    {
        [self.theScrollView addSubview:[self.scrollArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
   [super prepareForReuse];
   [[self.theScrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
   [self.scrollArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is on the right track, I think. Unfortunately `partWhereYouSetScrollArray` will be called multiple times too. In a tableView with reusable cells, that method will be called every time `scrollArray` is set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, leaving us with the same issue.

Comment: I see. Then remove all the subviews in prepareForReuse.

Comment: I added prepareForReuse.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too. It's having some unintended consequences. Other cell's subviews are being removed.

Comment: If you show me the part where you added the scrollview and cel's subviews, it would be more helpful.